# Workaround for bug where Android N device constantly enters / exits region when using Altbeacon

Tags: java, android, mobile, altbeacon

I have an Android app implementing the Altbeacon library to monitor for beacons while holding a reference to BackgroundPowerSaver(). This is working as expected except on Android N devices, where the library informs me that I am constantly entering/exiting a beacon region even though my device nor beacon are moving.

I have confirmed that this is a bug within the Altbeacon library as the reference app (linked below) also has the same issue when run on an Android N device. 
https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference

Is there a known work-around for this bug?

---

I am running the reference app with the 2.1.3 grade build on a Nexus 9 tablet with Android N and am monitoring for RadBeacon beacons. As seen in the LogCat statements, the app believes that it is entering and exiting the beacon region every ~15 seconds. However, the device nor the beacon are moving during this time. The beacon layout I have set my BeaconManager to find is "m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24".

[Here is the LogCat output.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxXHCeJN9LlJQ2t1UGhIbXprTmM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Any chance you can link to a full logcat excerpt when this happens, including system level messages?

Comment: Just added @davidgyoung

Comment: I see this in the logs.  `java.lang.SecurityException: Need ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to get scan results`.  I am surprised it works at all if location is not granted.  See here about granting permissions: https://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/09/29/is-your-beacon-app-ready-for-android-6.html

Comment: Location permissions are granted, a couple lines after that there is a log indicating that "coarse location permission granted". The "Need.." log appears when the permissions AlertDialog is closed, before the system permissions request appears for confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be caused by a change in Android N's Developer Preview 4:

> We’ve changed the BLE Scanning behavior starting in DP4. We’ll prevent applications from starting and stopping scans more than 5 times in 30 seconds. For long running scans, we’ll convert them into opportunistic scans

https://developer.android.com/preview/support.html

I've opened a [new issue on the Android Beacon Library Open Source Project](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/418) to address this change for Android Nougat devices.  Please monitor this issue for a preview fix to be released shortly.  If you'd be open to test a preview build, I'd certainly appreciate it.

**EDIT:**  A proposed fix is available [here.](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/pull/419)  Please follow the instructions on the linked page to test this build with your project and let me know if it resolves the problem.